# How to prepare separate Database for redis with python?

Tags: python, redis

Currently I'm accessing Redis using the host name and the port.

like

> r = redis.Redis(host=redisHost, port=redisPort)

1. Is there a way to mention a redis database and connect to that database from python ?
2. And then is there a way to create several redis databases for a single port ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a particular db to connect using:

```
r = redis.Redis(host=redisHost, port=redisPort, db=N)
```

where N is the db number

Comment: Thanks Isaan. Is there a way to create databases on redis or they are still there ? like 0,1,2,3 ...\

Comment: @ChamithMalinda There's no need to create them, just use them.

Comment: @ChamithMalinda - no you cant create.By default you have 16 dbs numbered 0-15.You can increase the number of databases by changing the database setting in the redis config file